# How to run an ASCIImatics animation only one time in Python?

Tags: python, animation, asciimatics

I'm trying to get the animation from ASCIImatics to run only one time then break into my normal code. Like an intro you could say. Is there a way to only run the animation one time then once you hit space bar it'll break the animation and go to the normal code body? Currently the animation runs on a loop after you hit space bar, and as I said I'm trying to only have it run once. Thanks!

```
from random import randint
from asciimatics.effects import Print
from asciimatics.particles import Explosion, StarFirework, DropScreen, Rain, \
    ShootScreen
from asciimatics.renderers import SpeechBubble, FigletText, Rainbow
from asciimatics.scene import Scene
from asciimatics.screen import Screen
from asciimatics.exceptions import ResizeScreenError
import sys
from asciimatics.effects import Cycle, Stars
import time
 
def demo(screen):
    screen.set_title("ASCIIMATICS demo")
 
    scenes = []
 
    # First scene: title page
    effects = [
        Stars
            (screen, 200),
        Cycle(screen,
              Rainbow(screen, FigletText("Welcome to", font="big")),
              y=screen.height // 4 - 5),
        Print(screen,
              Rainbow(screen, FigletText("K y l e ' s   M i n i   G a m e s !", font="big")),
              screen.height // 2 - 3,
              start_frame=7),
        Cycle(screen,
              SpeechBubble("Press space bar to play"),
              screen.height - 3,
              #transparent=False,
              start_frame=10)
    ]
    scenes.append(Scene(effects, 0, clear=True))
 
    # Next scene: just dissolve the title.
    effects = [
        ShootScreen(screen, screen.width // 2, screen.height // 2, 100),
    ]
    scenes.append(Scene(effects, 10, clear=False))

    screen.play(scenes, stop_on_resize=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        try:
            Screen.wrapper(demo)
        except ResizeScreenError:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want to achieve...

If you just want to play through all your Scenes once, simply specify `repeat=False` when you call `play()`.  This will move on from the first `Scene` when you press space and will automatically stop after 10 frames on the second `Scene` (as specified by your code).

However, if you want to ensure that the space bar has no effect while you clear the screen in that second `Scene`, you'd need to create a custom `Scene` to catch and ignore the space bar.  The `GameController` class in the ray_casting.py demo shows how to do this.